# Cant create HTML document from Hwnd using C#

Tags: c#

We have an existing piece of software that uses shellwidnows to access an internet explorer page and modify data on a form. However, we are porting it to Citrix seamless application and shell windows does not work there.

I have looked around on the internet and found a way to create a HtmlDocument from an existing IE window.

However, I am having a problem when trying to run "SendMessageTimeout". It runs without error but the result returned is 0 when it should be a non-zero amount. And thus, I can not go to the next phase of creating the HTML Document.

The line causing the problem is:
IntPtr result = SendMessageTimeout(htmlWindow, lMsg, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, SendMessageTimeoutFlags.SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 1000, out  lRes);

Here is the full code. Iam using VS 2008 due  to corporate conventions. I am new to C# so some conventions and styling may be incorrect. Thanks for any help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using mshtml;
using System.Diagnostics;

public delegate bool IECallBack(int hwnd, int lParam);
public delegate bool IEChildCallBack(int hWndParent, int lpEnumFunc, int lParam);

namespace GetIEWindows
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        [DllImport("Oleacc.Dll")]
        public static extern int ObjectFromLresult(UIntPtr lResult, UUID _riid, int wParam, mshtml.HTMLDocument _ppvObject);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindowEx")]
        private static extern int FindWindowEx(int parentWindow, int childWindow, string _ClassName, string _WindowName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow")]
        private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

        [DllImport("user32.Dll")]
        public static extern int EnumWindows(IECallBack x, long y);

        [DllImport("user32.Dll")]
        public static extern int EnumChildWindows(int parent, IECallBack x, long y);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr GetWindow(IntPtr hWnd, GetWindow_Cmd uCmd);

        [DllImport("User32.Dll")]
        public static extern void GetWindowText(IntPtr h, StringBuilder s, long nMaxCount);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern int GetWindowTextLength(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("User32.Dll")]
        public static extern void GetClassName(int h, StringBuilder s, int
        nMaxCount);

        [DllImport("User32.Dll")]
        public static extern uint RegisterWindowMessage(string lpString);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern IntPtr SendMessageTimeout(IntPtr windowHandle, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, SendMessageTimeoutFlags flags, uint timeout, out UIntPtr result);

        enum GetWindow_Cmd : uint
        {
            GW_HWNDFIRST = 0,
            GW_HWNDLAST = 1,
            GW_HWNDNEXT = 2,
            GW_HWNDPREV = 3,
            GW_OWNER = 4,
            GW_CHILD = 5,
            GW_ENABLEDPOPUP = 6
        }

        [Flags]
        public enum SendMessageTimeoutFlags : uint
        {
            SMTO_NORMAL = 0x0,
            SMTO_BLOCK = 0x1,
            SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG = 0x2,
            SMTO_NOTIMEOUTIFNOTHUNG = 0x8
        }

        public const int SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG = 0x2;


        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public struct UUID
        {
            public long Data1;
            public int Data2;
            public int Data3;
            [MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
            public byte[] Data4;
        }

        public static mshtml.HTMLDocument GetHTMLContent(IntPtr htmlWindow)
        {
            HTMLDocument htmlDocument = new mshtml.HTMLDocument();
            HTMLDocument thedoc = new mshtml.HTMLDocument();
            IHTMLDocument htmlDoc = null;

            Guid guid = new Guid("626FC520-A41E-11cf-A731-00A0C9082637");
            int foundWindow = htmlWindow.ToInt32();
            string htmlContent = "";


            UUID IID_IHTMLDocument = new UUID();
            UIntPtr lRes;
            uint lMsg = 0;
            int hr = 0;

            if (foundWindow != 0)
            {
                // Register the message 
                lMsg = RegisterWindowMessage("WM_HTML_GETOBJECT");
                //lMsg = RegisterWindowMessage("WM_GETTEXT");

                // Get the object 
                IntPtr result = SendMessageTimeout(htmlWindow, lMsg, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, SendMessageTimeoutFlags.SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 1000, out  lRes);
                if (result.ToInt32() != 0)
                {
                    if (lRes != UIntPtr.Zero)
                    {
                        // Initialize the interface ID 
                        IID_IHTMLDocument.Data1 = 0x626FC520;
                        IID_IHTMLDocument.Data2 = 0xA41E;
                        IID_IHTMLDocument.Data3 = 0x11CF;


                        IID_IHTMLDocument.Data4 = new byte[8];
                        IID_IHTMLDocument.Data4[0] = 0xA7;
                        IID_IHTMLDocument.Data4[1] = 0x31;
                        IID_IHTMLDocument.Data4[2] = 0x0;
                        IID_IHTMLDocument.Data4[3] = 0xA0;
                        IID_IHTMLDocument.Data4[4] = 0xC9;
                        IID_IHTMLDocument.Data4[5] = 0x8;
                        IID_IHTMLDocument.Data4[6] = 0x26;
                        IID_IHTMLDocument.Data4[7] = 0x37;


                        // Get the object from lRes 
                        try
                        {
                            hr = ObjectFromLresult(lRes, IID_IHTMLDocument, 0, thedoc);
                            //htmlDoc = (mshtml.IHTMLDocument)ObjectFromLresult(, IID_IHTMLDocument, 0, htmlDoc);
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Did not get IHTMLDocument: " + e.Message);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return thedoc;
        }

        public static void getHWnd()
        {
            string currentTitle;
            string windowName = null;
            string windowClass = "#32770";
            HTMLDocument pageToBeEdited;
            IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow(windowClass, windowName);
            while (hWnd.ToInt32() != 0) {
                int length       = GetWindowTextLength(hWnd);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length + 1);

                GetWindowText(hWnd, sb, sb.Capacity);

                currentTitle = sb.ToString();
                if (currentTitle.Contains("Internet Explorer")) {
                    pageToBeEdited = GetHTMLContent(hWnd);
                    return;
                }
                hWnd = GetWindow(hWnd, GetWindow_Cmd.GW_HWNDNEXT);
            }

            return;

        }
        private void btnRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            getHWnd();
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

For anybody who is interested, the problem was resolved by using a different way of getHWnd:

```
public static IntPtr getHWnd(string title)
    {
        IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow(null, title);
        BringWindowToTop(hWnd);
        SetActiveWindow(hWnd);
        SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcessesByName("IExplore"))
        {
            if (process.MainWindowTitle.ToLower().Contains(title.ToLower()))
            {
                hWnd = process.MainWindowHandle;
                break;
            }
        }

        EnumProc proc = new EnumProc(EnumWindows);
        EnumChildWindows(hWnd, proc, ref hWnd);
        return hWnd;

    }

    public HTMLDocument GetHTMLDocument(IntPtr hWnd)
    {
        HTMLDocument document = null;
        int iMsg = 0;
        int iRes = 0;

        iMsg = RegisterWindowMessage("WM_HTML_GETOBJECT");
        if (iMsg != 0)
        {
            SendMessageTimeout(hWnd, iMsg, 0, 0, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 1000, out iRes);
            if (iRes != 0)
            {
                int hr = ObjectFromLresult(iRes, ref IID_IHTMLDocument, 0, ref document);
            }
        }
        return document;
    }

    private static int EnumWindows(IntPtr hWnd, ref IntPtr lParam)
    {
        int iRet = 1;
        StringBuilder classname = new StringBuilder(128);
        GetClassName(hWnd, classname, classname.Capacity);
        if ((bool)(string.Compare(classname.ToString(), "Internet Explorer_Server") == 0))
        {
            lParam = hWnd;
            iRet = 0;
        }
        return iRet;
    }
```

Comment: RegisterWindowMessage() returns a Uint how are you assigning it to iMsg?

Comment: it works for ie window. When I try to do the same for embedded ie control I have "Call was rejected by callee. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010001 (RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED)) "

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can get HTMLDocument using Hwnd :

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using mshtml;

    namespace HookBrowser
    {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        #region API CALLS

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetClassNameA")]
        public static extern int GetClassName(IntPtr hwnd, StringBuilder lpClassName, int nMaxCount);

        /*delegate to handle EnumChildWindows*/
        public delegate int EnumProc(IntPtr hWnd, ref IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int EnumChildWindows(IntPtr hWndParent, EnumProc lpEnumFunc, ref  IntPtr lParam);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "RegisterWindowMessageA")]
        public static extern int RegisterWindowMessage(string lpString);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessageTimeoutA")]
        public static extern int SendMessageTimeout(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, int wParam, int lParam, int fuFlags, int uTimeout, out int lpdwResult);
        [DllImport("OLEACC.dll")]
        public static extern int ObjectFromLresult(int lResult, ref Guid riid, int wParam, ref IHTMLDocument2 ppvObject);
        public const int SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG = 0x2;
        public Guid IID_IHTMLDocument = new Guid("626FC520-A41E-11CF-A731-00A0C9082637");

        #endregion

        public IHTMLDocument2 document;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            document = documentFromDOM();
            /// check that we have hold of the IHTMLDocument2...
            if (!(bool)(document == null))
            {
                this.Text = document.url;
            }
        }

        private IHTMLDocument2 documentFromDOM()
        {
            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("iexplore");
            if (processes.Length > 0)
            {
                IntPtr hWnd = processes[0].MainWindowHandle;
                int lngMsg = 0;
                int lRes;

                EnumProc proc = new EnumProc(EnumWindows);
                EnumChildWindows(hWnd, proc, ref hWnd);
                if (!hWnd.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
                {
                    lngMsg = RegisterWindowMessage("WM_HTML_GETOBJECT");
                    if (lngMsg != 0)
                    {
                        SendMessageTimeout(hWnd, lngMsg, 0, 0, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 1000, out lRes);
                        if (!(bool)(lRes == 0))
                        {
                            int hr = ObjectFromLresult(lRes, ref IID_IHTMLDocument, 0, ref document);
                            if ((bool)(document == null))
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("NoLDocument Found!", "Warning");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return document;
        }

        private int EnumWindows(IntPtr hWnd, ref IntPtr lParam)
        {
            int retVal = 1;
            StringBuilder classname = new StringBuilder(128);
            GetClassName(hWnd, classname, classname.Capacity);
            /// check if the instance we have found is Internet Explorer_Server
            if ((bool)(string.Compare(classname.ToString(), "Internet Explorer_Server") == 0))
            {
                lParam = hWnd;
                retVal = 0;
            }
            return retVal;
        }
    }
}
```

Please refer to this link for more info :

http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/code-library/295336-internet-explorer-dom-using-objectfromlresult.html

Comment: Please do not only post links as answers but put the relevant steps in your actual answer. The external side might be unavailable or change, rendering your answer useless. Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy 
the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing 
your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always 
leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your 
material...